# PCA on limited data in generative model latent space: what does almost 100% of variance captured mean?

Tags: python, pca

I am studying the latent space of a generative model, where the data in my latent space have a shape of (64, 64, 3). I would like to visualize a subset of this data, say n=5, in a 2D plot. To achieve this, I have reshaped the data to have a shape of (5, 12288) and used PCA to reduce it to the first 2 principal components, which I then plot using matplotlib.

However, I am uncertain about the amount of variance captured by the PCA. When I check, it shows that more than 99% of the variance is captured. I think this might be due to the small number of samples that I used, such that the singular values can only be at most 5 in this case. Is my understanding correct? Does this mean that the variance captured by the PCA is not meaningful for the full latent space?

Here is the code I used to reshape my data, reduce it with PCA, and check the captured variance:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

def matrix_to_point(A):
    # Convert a matrix to a point by flattening it
    return A.reshape(-1)

n = 5
latent_sample = np.random.rand(n, *(64, 64, 3))
data =  np.asarray([ matrix_to_point(m) for m in latent_sample])

pca= PCA(n_components=2)
pca = pca.fit(data)

reduced_data = pca.transform(data)

print(f'Variance captured by the PCA: {pca.explained_variance_ratio_}')
#output with the posted code: Variance captured by the PCA: [0.25629761 0.25391076]
#output with the complete code: Variance captured by the PCA: [0.96852827 0.03129395]
```

In this code, I substituted the actual latent sample with some random samples to make it executable. Thank you in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try judging the quality of the PCA by inversely transforming the reduced data and judge the result, here I used RSME, but you can use another metric if that suits your use case better:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

def matrix_to_point(A):
    # Convert a matrix to a point by flattening it
    return A.reshape(-1)

n = 5
latent_sample = np.random.rand(n, *(64, 64, 3))
data =  np.asarray([ matrix_to_point(m) for m in latent_sample])

pca= PCA(n_components=2)
pca = pca.fit(data)

reduced_data = pca.transform(data)
print(f'Variance captured by the PCA: {pca.explained_variance_ratio_}')

expanded_data = pca.inverse_transform(reduced_data)
rmse = np.mean(np.sqrt((expanded_data - data)**2))
print(f'Root mean square error: {rmse}')
```

In case your data is actually a two-dimensional subspace of the entire space, the fit will be very good and the RSME will be very small.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I attempted to reconstruct the original data and assess the quality of the reconstruction. As expected, the reconstructed data closely resemble the original data, which is consistent with the captured variance. Although the latent space is expected to be vast, the strong correlation between the samples may explain why only two principal components were sufficient to almost perfectly reconstruct the original sample.

Comment: glad to hear the suggestion helped and curious that you have such a strong linear(?) subspace. most of your variance seems to be captured in one, rather than two dimensions. Please accept the answer if this solved your question.(checkmark icon)